# Lucene: How to index and search multiple value under single field

Tags: lucene

How to index and search multiple value under single field.

e.g. say i have a field **processor** which might have **i3,i5,i7** or **i3** or **i3,i5** values.
now imagine a laptop data as below:

**data1:**

```
 name= laptop name
 price = laptop price
 processor=core duo
```

**data2:**

```
 name= laptop name
 price = laptop price
 processor=i3,i5
```

**data3:**

```
 name= laptop name
 price = laptop price
 processor=i3,i5,i7
```

Now,

if a user want to search only i3 and i5 processor it should show data2 & data3 only.

So my question is how should i **index** and **search** the lucene. I am using lucene 4.4.

I checked  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401754/field-having-multiple-distinct-values) but could not understand as no example was there. An example will be good for me.

Answer (score 7):

Frankly, there isn't really much to it.  Using using `StandardAnalyzer` and the standard `QueryParser`, you would simply add the field to the document, in the form shown, like:

```
Document document = new Document();
document.add(new TextField("name", "laptop name"));
document.add(new TextField("processor", "i3,i5,i7"));
//Add other fields as needed...
//Assuming you've set up your writing to use StandardAnalyzer...
writer.addDocument(document);
```

StandardAnalyzer will tokenize on punctuation (and whitespace, etc), indexing the tokens "i3", "i5" and "i7" in the "processor" field, so when using just using the standard `QueryParser` (see [query parser syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Overview)), the query:

```
processor:(i3 i5)
```

Will find any fields with either an "i3" or "i5" in the "processor" field

Answer (score 0):

You can inspire by my source code: http://git.abclinuxu.cz/?p=abclinuxu.git;a=tree;f=src/cz/abclinuxu/utils/search;h=d825ec75da1b19ca0cd6065458fec771de174be9;hb=HEAD

MyDocument is POJO that constructs LuceneDocument. Important information is stored in Field, so it is searchable. My document type is similar to your processor type:

```
Field field = new Field(TYPE, type, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED);
```

Each processor type shall be stored individually.