# Adding a multi-valued string field to a Lucene Document, do commas matter?

Tags: java, lucene

I'm building a Lucene Index and adding Documents.

I have a field that is multi-valued, for this example I'll use Categories.

An Item can have many categories, for example, Jeans can fall under Clothing, Pants, Men's, Women's, etc.

When adding the field to a document, do commas make a difference? Will Lucene simply ignore them? if I change commas to spaces will there be a difference? Does this automatically make the field multi-valued?

```
String categoriesForItem = getCategories(); // returns "category1, category2, cat3" from a DB call

categoriesForItem = categoriesForItem.replaceAll(",", " ").trim(); // not sure if to remove comma

doc.add(new StringField("categories", categoriesForItem , Field.Store.YES)); // doc is a Document
```

Am I doing this correctly? or is there another way to create multivalued fields?

Any help/advice is appreciated.

Comment: I'm using the latest lucene (currently 4.6)

Comment: not about your real question but does the field has to be stored? is more like searching for items under category 'pANTS' than searching for Jeans and retrieving all of its category, isn't it?

Comment: Well, I'd like to support both kinds of searches. Search for a product and get its categories (as an added filter) and searching for items under a category as well and getting it's products. I'm fairly new to Lucene, so I'm not sure whether to store the field or not, so I'm defaulting to storing it.

Comment: I would recommend then creating two indexes, one for categories and another for items, they will work faster.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This would be a better way to index multiValued fields per document

```
String categoriesForItem = getCategories(); // get "category1, category2, cat3" from a DB call

String [] categoriesForItems = categoriesForItem.split(","); 
for(String cat : categoriesForItems) {
    doc.add(new StringField("categories", cat , Field.Store.YES)); // doc is a Document 
}
```

Whenever multiple fields with the same name appear in one document, both the inverted index and term vectors will logically append the tokens of the field to one another, in the order the fields were added.

Also during the analysis phase two different values will be seperated by a position increment via setPositionIncrementGap() automatically. Let me explain why this is needed.

Your field "categories" in Document D1 has two values - "foo bar" and "foo baz"
Now if you were to do a phrase query "bar foo" D1 should not come up. This is ensure by adding an extra increment between two values of the same field.

If you yourself concatenate the field values and rely on the analyzer to split it into multiple values "bar foo" would return D1 which would be incorrect.

Comment: one more thing @varunthacker, how can I retrieve all values for this field in the document later? when I do doc.getField("store_number").toString() it only gives me one one value, the last one inserted.

Comment: Made that a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21049069/lucene-retrieve-all-values-for-a-multi-valued-field-in-a-document

Comment: This method doesn't really make the field multivalued, its just the multiple fields with the same name.

Comment: You probably want to set the  position increment gap in your Analyzer to a value different than 0 if you want this to work correctly. You can do this by using the Builder or overiding the getPositionIncrementGap in Analyzer

Answer (score 1):

If you use the StandardAnalyzer it is ok to have commas or spaces. But if you have another Analyzer, it depends.

Another way: You can have multiple times the same field with another category in it. Then I would recommend to use KeywordAnalyzer or let it be untokenized to have exact match of your category name.

Comment: Thanks. That helps, but can you elaborate? or point me to a link that goes into more detail?

Comment: @EliteOctagon He is referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947385/lucene-how-to-index-and-search-multiple-value-under-single-field

Comment: @EliteOctagon I would look at the documentation of StandardAnalyzer. Then you know how your text is split up into what kind of tokens. If it's important for you that your category names are exact, i.e. case sensitive, then use multiple fields and do not let analyze them.