# Lucene - retrieve all values for a multi-valued field in a document

Tags: java, lucene, document

I added a field in Lucene which is multi-valued as such:

```
String categoriesForItem = getCategories(); // returns "category1, category2, cat3" from a DB call

String [] categoriesForItems = categoriesForItem.split(","; 
for(String cat : categoriesForItems) {
    doc.add(new StringField("categories", cat , Field.Store.YES)); // doc is a Document 
}
```

later when I am searching for items in a category everything works as expected, but when I get a Document and do:

```
String categories= doc.getField("categories").stringValue();
```

I only get the last inserted value for that document rather than all the values that were added for that document.

How can I get all the values which were added for that document?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are adding to the document is not multi-valued single field, but multiple fields with the same name. At the end you are only retrieving one field.

Use `public final List<IndexableField> getFields()` of `Document` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Use `doc.getValues("categories")`.