# How can be "schema.xml" in Solr replaced in Lucene?

Tags: solr, lucene, lucene.net

I currently try to migrate from Solr to Lucene.NET and cannot find a way to implement functionality of `schema.xml`.

How the same things `shema.xml` does can be achieved in Lucene/Lucene.NET?

Comment: Hi Andy, please add more details to your question so community members can help you.
For example, exactly what do you want to migrate, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr (like Elasticsearch) is built on top of Lucene. It provides some nice features on top of Lucene like the schema - basically an XML specification of what you would do programmatically with Lucene API.

For example you want to add a multi-valued string field called categories that is also stored in the index:-

```
String categoriesForItem = getCategories();

String [] categoriesForItems = categoriesForItem.split(","); 
for(String cat : categoriesForItems) {
    doc.add(new StringField("categories", cat , Field.Store.YES));
}
```

from here: [Adding a multi-valued string field to a Lucene Document, do commas matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002042/adding-a-multi-valued-string-field-to-a-lucene-document-do-commas-matter)