# Lucene Search Syntax

Tags: c#, search, lucene.net

I need help figuring out which query types to use in given situations.

I think i'm right in saying that if i stored the word "FORD" in a lucene Field and i wanted to find an exact match i would use a `TermQuery`?

But which query type should i use if I was looking for the word "FORD" where the contents of the field where stored as :-

> "FORD|HONDA|SUZUKI"

What if i was to search the contents of an entire page, looking for a phrase? such as "please help me"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to search FORD in `FORD|HONDA|SUZUKI`, either index with *Field.Index.ANALYZED*, or store it as below to use *TermQuery*

```
var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);
var fs = FSDirectory.Open("test.index");

//Index a Test Document
IndexWriter wr = new IndexWriter(fs, analyzer, true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED);
var doc = new Document();

doc.Add(new Field("Model", "FORD", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
doc.Add(new Field("Model", "HONDA", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
doc.Add(new Field("Model", "SUZUKI", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));

doc.Add(new Field("Text", @"What if i was to search the contents of an entire page, looking for a phrase? such as ""please help me""?", 
                    Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

wr.AddDocument(doc);
wr.Commit();

var reader = wr.GetReader();
var searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

//Use TermQuery for "NOT_ANALYZED" fields
var result = searcher.Search(new TermQuery(new Term("Model", "FORD")), 100);
foreach (var item in result.ScoreDocs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("1)" + reader.Document(item.Doc).GetField("Text").StringValue);
}

//Use QueryParser for "ANALYZED" fields
var qp = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, "Text", analyzer);
result = searcher.Search(qp.Parse(@"""HELP ME"""), 100);
foreach (var item in result.ScoreDocs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("2)" + reader.Document(item.Doc).GetField("Text").StringValue);
}
```

*TermQuery* means you want to search the term as it is stored in index which depends on how you indexed that field(NOT_ANALYZED, ANALYZED+WhichAnalyzer). Most common use of it is with *NOT_ANALYZED* fields.

You can use *TermQuery* with *ANALYZED* fields too, but then you should know how the *analyzer* tokenizes your input string. Below is a sample to see what how analyzers tokenize your input

```
var text = @"What if i was to search the contents of an entire page, looking for a phrase? such as ""please help me""?";
var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30 );
//var analyzer = new WhitespaceAnalyzer();
//var analyzer = new KeywordAnalyzer();
//var analyzer = new SimpleAnalyzer();

var ts = analyzer.TokenStream("", new StringReader(text));
var termAttr = ts.GetAttribute<ITermAttribute>();

while (ts.IncrementToken())
{
    Console.Write("[" + termAttr.Term + "] " );    
}
```

Comment: When would you choose to set a field as ANALYZED? when its contents are large in size? eg, a description or summary?

Comment: @Derek Most of the time you will have to use analyzed. *NOT_ANALYZED* fields can not be used(well not always correct) with QueryParser. I generally use *NOT_ANALYZED* for fields like ID, Model, Color etc. If you want to make a search like *google* (any *word* in the text) use *ANALYZED*. BTW: Lucene/Lucene.Net has a mailing list where great people can help you more

Comment: So if i was looking to add a field that contained say, the page of a book, and i wanted to search that field for  a key phrase or word. I should set the field as ANALYZED, and use the QueryParser?

Comment: Yes...(But QueryParser is not a must, You can build your own query with BooleanQuery. QueryParser only automates it)

Comment: Well, Thats what i was doing, I built a Boolean Query, that contained two Term Query's that MUST Occur. But i was not getting any results back. I had set the Fields to be Analysed originally, and the search brought back no results. I re-indexed so that those fields were no longer ANALYZED, and it worked. The two fields where like Id or Model, one word Data.

Comment: @Derek *NOT_ANALYZED* means "store that text as it is". So you have to search it as it is (TermQuery). When I say *as it is*, I mean exact match(Same Upper/lower cases, spaces etc.) Just play a liitle bit with above code and see how Lucene works before continueing with your code.

Answer (score 1):

I would turn the problem sideways, so I put the multiple values for each field separately in the index -- this should make searching simpler. Looking at [Field Having Multiple Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401754/field-having-multiple-distinct-values) might be helpful.